# How can I unbound package name and SHA1 fingerprint?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

We have an app 'TinyScan' live on Google Play already. In the next update, we are going to integrate Google Drive into our app. For the development, we used a test account to register an android key with the right package name and test SHA1 fingerprint. Now we are going to submit the app to Google Play and found that we can not use our major account to register the android key for the package name and SHA1 fingerprint although we have deleted the project and key in test account.

Shortly, now we have two SHA1 fingerprints, one is used for live version of the app (production SHA1) and other is just for development (development SHA1). We had package name bound with development SHA1 which does not match the one used for live version of the app. I thought if you google guys can unbound this pair so that we can register app for the package name with production SHA1? Now it keeps reminding me 'Error (projectId=530215234379) OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY_ALREADY_EXISTS: OAuthClient key exists'. if we try to register package name with production SHA1.

Thanks

Comment: Any response google guys?

Comment: I have two projects with the same package name, one using the debug signing key hash and one the release - i only get this error if I try to create another project with an already used package and hash combo...

Comment: If your two projects are hold by same google account, that should be OK. But if try to create the project by another account, it says the Client ID is global unique and is in use although you have delete the project from your original account. What a strange.